# My datasource is Azure Synapse. Do I still need a gateway to be set up in this case?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-synapse, gateway, workspace

Our new data source for Power BI reports is Azure Synapse. Do we still need a gateway to be set up in this case? . I think this is the reason that we can’t refresh the data in Power BI.

Thanks!

I see after clicking on ‘edit credentials’. I tried both OAuth2 and username/password authentication and received the same error message. I think the gateway is missing to enable private endpoint as per error message .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share the error message.

Everything depends on the network configuration of synapse server.
In case if the server is not configured within any vnet, you can access synapse via power bi without any gateway as both are hosted on cloud.
In case if synapse is within vnet, you need to set up a gateway within a server hosted within the vnet

Comment: there is the info:     Failed to update data source credentials: Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network option.

Comment: yes, you would need a gateway to refresh the powerbi